# "this" is not defined inside function in reactJs

Tags: reactjs

> I'm beginner in reactjs ,I'm trying to set materials in the api
>   response but "this" become undefined so i can't call
>   this.setMaterials(materials) Why does this become undefined in
>   getMaterials() function?

```
   constructor() {
        super();
        this.obj = {
            materials: []
        };
    }
    getMaterials(string) {
        var options = {
            url: 'materials',
            method: 'get',
        };
        http.makeRequest(options).then(res => {
            console.log(this)// undefined
            this.setMaterials(res); //try to set materials in the obj variable
        });
    }

    setMaterials(materials) {
        this.obj.materials = materials;
    }

render(){
    return(
       <IntegrationDownshift  getItems={this.getMaterials.bind(this)}  />
          )
       }
```

Comment: You aren't calling `setMaterials()`... you are calling `materials()` as function instead

Comment: Posted code won't result in undefined `this`. Whatever the problem is, the question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

you should either bind your functions in your constructor to your component to this or use the new scope as you should define arrow functions in order to bind the function automatically to the component like:

```
setMaterials = (materials)=> {
  this.obj.materials = materials;
}
```

so from anywhere in the code, you can call this.setMaterials, and the getMaterials function also: (so you can call this inside of it without manually binding the function)

```
getMaterials = (string) => {
    var options = {
        url: 'materials',
        method: 'get',
    };
    http.makeRequest(options).then(res => {
        console.log(this)// undefined
        this.setMaterials(res); //try to set materials in the obj 
         variable
    });
}
```